# How to assign a variable and not reference it

Tags: ruby

If it's not a bug, then it's really unintuitive that `=` sometimes assigns variables, and sometimes points to them.

```
a = {a:'a'}
b = a 

puts a #=> {:a=>"a"}
puts b #=> {:a=>"a"}
puts a == b #=> true

a.merge! bob:'b' 
puts a #=> {:a=>"a", :bob=>"b"}
puts b #=> {:a=>"a", :bob=>"b"}
puts a == b #=> true
```

This was tested on:

- Ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
- Ruby 2.7.0dev (2019-09-24T02:50:38Z trunk 2366c68116) [x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: This isn't really a ruby specific thing. Most all programming languages have similar behavior when assigning objects.

Comment: Just something to think about... http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm368. Actually that whole page is a great thing to read.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the assignment operator and will always assign a value to something, however variables always hold references to objects and don't contain the object itself.

In your first case you create a new hash `{a:'a'}` and assign its reference to `a`. Then you assign the reference held by `a` to `b`. Therefore mutating `a` will also mutate `b`. If you don't want this [`clone`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) or [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)licate your object first. Both methods create a copy of the receiver and return the reference of the copy. (Check the documentation for differences, most of the time you're looking for `dup`.)

```
a = {a: 'a'}
b = a.dup

a.merge!(bob: 'b')
puts a, b
# {:a=>"a", :bob=>"b"}
# {:a=>"a"}
#=> nil
```

Alternatively you could use non-mutating methods. These return a new instance of the object.

```
a = {a: 'a'}
b = a.merge(bob: 'b')
puts a, b
# {:a=>"a"}
# {:a=>"a", :bob=>"b"}
#=> nil
```

In the above example I use [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) without `!`, which creates a new hash and returns its reference and doesn't mutate the receiver.

Since all we work with in Ruby are references to objects, we leave out the reference part and simply say that `merge` returns a new hash, instead of saying that it returns a reference to a new hash.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, while also this is not really unintuitive.

In Ruby, everything is an object. When you are doing `b = a` you're actually saying that `b` and `a` point to the same object. When the object is mutated, both of them point to the same new mutated object.

For a very detailed explanation, see "[Is Ruby pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/)" which is kind of old, but still relevant.

Comment: You mean, "everything is an object, except for variables, blocks, keywords, some operators, comments and some other bits".